# Get Average Value of a Field

Tags: drupal

I'm using integer fields for a review system in Drupal.

I would like to add up all the values of a specific integer field (globally), and then divide that by the number of fields to get the average. I can get the total integer value of one node, but I want to get the value of all the nodes with a specific node reference.

I've tried looking around for solutions using computed fields and views php, but I have limited php skills.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for this:

https://drupal.org/node/1308114

Comment: I've tried to use Fivestar for my rating system, but there's a few issues with it. 1) I want to display the results in a chart, and I'm not sure if any of the chart modules will work with VotingApi - not that I've seen anyway. And 2) Using integers would allow me to have a review system based on scale (-2, -1, 0, 1, 2), as opposed to just 1-5.

Comment: that being said, my original preference was to use votingapi. but the Rate module doesn't integrate with fields (which I need), and I've had the aforementioned issues with Fivestar.